# How can I read chat on a minecraft server using RCON?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got a python script that can execute commands through RCON like /say or /list. But I want to be able to read what my friends are saying in my sever, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

## You can't.

RCON does not support a scrolling (streaming) console, it only supports incoming traffic and one response, like a REST protocol. You could try `ssh`-ing or `mstsc`-ing (Microsoft Remote Desktop (lit: Terminal Services)) into your server with your server running in a container (for example, on Linux, this is in a [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) [(external tutorial)](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)).

You can't do this in [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), nor can you do it in any Source game such as [counter-strike-global-offensive](/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive), [team-fortress-2](/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) or [dota-2](/questions/tagged/dota-2), where the protocol originated from.

Comment: From a suggested edit: "No, the protocol actually orgininates from Minecraft"

Comment: [No, it actually originated from Source](https://wiki.vg/RCON). Just slightly modified.